# AHK if statement not correctly comparing variables

Tags: if-statement, autohotkey

Here is what i am trying to do,

step 1 get the color of the mouse location

step 2 enter the loop

step 3 get the second color of the new mouse location

step 4 compare the two colors

error = no matter what the output of color 1 or color 2 the script below is stating true.

```
!^b::
MouseGetPos, MouseX, MouseY
PixelGetColor, color, %MouseX%, %MouseY%
sleep, 5000
loop
{
    MouseGetPos, MouseX, MouseY
    PixelGetColor, color2, %MouseX%, %MouseY%   
    if (%color%=%color2%)
    {
        MsgBox, it matchs %color% = %color2%
        sleep,5000
    }
    else
    {
        MsgBox, It dosnt match %color% != %color2%
        sleep, 5000
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with `if (%color%=%color2%)`

Once you declare an `if` statement like this, you do not need to enclose variables with the `%var%`. Instead, you can replace the line with `if (color==color2)`.

Full code:

```
!^b::
MouseGetPos, MouseX, MouseY
PixelGetColor, color, %MouseX%, %MouseY%
sleep, 5000
loop
{
    MouseGetPos, MouseX, MouseY
    PixelGetColor, color2, %MouseX%, %MouseY%   
    if (color==color2)
    {
        MsgBox, it matchs %color% = %color2%
        sleep,5000
    }
    else
    {
        MsgBox, It dosnt match %color% != %color2%
        sleep, 5000
    }

}
```